# Wanting to know what type of tree I have

Tags: identification

I don’t think it has ever fruit but I have not taken care of it it has gotten bigger reddish green leave I would like to know what it is to take care of it and maybe get it to fruit smooth bark on the trunk

[image: trunk]

Comment: Even without fruit, does it flower?  If so, a photo would help a lot. — Have you tried [Pl@ntNet identify](https://identify.plantnet.org/)? Though again, a photo with flowers would be a lot more useful.

Comment: Overall tree shape is important to species ident. A picture with the whole tree would help. Also, a rough estimate of age if possible.

Comment: I’m not sure how to post another picture of it

Answer (score 2):

*[It could be a fruit tree, but as the comments say, pictures of the flowers, if any, would be more diagnostic. If there are never any flowers, there won't be any fruit.]*

Without knowing that, general tree-health improvement advice:

I'm inferring as your picture does not show much about the tree's situation, but it has the implication that it's set in mowed lawn.

Wipe out the grass at least 3 feet out from the trunk, or to the dripline, (*i.e.* as far out as the branches reach) for one thing. Keep lawn mowers and string trimmers *away* from the trunk. Grass is competition for nutrition, and grass equipment can seriously damage tree bark, which seriously damages the tree.

*Put up some nice sharply focused pictures of the flowers when they happen, if they do.*

Comment: When the tree is small or struggling, grass and weeds need to be kept back as you suggest. When it is larger and healthy the grass is probably overall better (very slightly) because it will slow soil drying out. The other advice is excellent.

Comment: Mulch is better than grass for that.

Answer (score 2):

If it is not a fruit tree, the rest of this post is not relevant. Looking at the leaves it *might* be an apple tree. But this is by no means definite. Need to see the whole tree. And need to know roughly how old it is. Here are a couple images of apple trees.

[image]

[image]

There are many varieties of apple tree. Many more wild varieties. They each have different shapes and reach different sizes when mature.  But the general outline is the sort of "blob" shape in the image.

If it is a fruit tree, it may not flower until it reaches a large size and has a healthy root system. This is because the tree must support the weight of the fruit when it ripens. A smaller tree could break under the load of fruit.

Again, if it is a fruit tree, there are care steps you should be taking. For example, you should be thinking about pruning. You want to encourage the branches in such a way that when the branches are under load from fruit they can support it. The idea is an umbrella shape. When the branches are heavy with fruit they hang down. This is in comparison to having a branch poking upwards or straight out. Such branches tend to snap off under heavy loads of fruit.

Comment: I’m not sure how to post another picture but it has some thorn like things on it

Answer (score 0):

[image: finally I was able to upload a full photo here]

Here is a full photo I figure out finally to post it kind of has thorns on it

Comment: The answer section is for answers only.  I have shifted the image to your question.  Please deleted this answer.

Comment: @RohitGupta says "*I have shifted the image to your question.*" — Actually, to Boba Fit's answer.

Comment: Oops, fixed it now

Comment: Thorns tend to suggests not an apple tree. The multiple trunks also suggests not an apple tree. There are a lot of trees and shrubs with thorns.  Considering the situation, it's likely a commercial variety used by landscape companies.  Possibly you could Google up a tree identification web site and find it.